# displaying icon image inside content property in IDE

Tags: css

[the picture of code, in "content" property, it's value is a shape!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaDvQ.png)
,
as you see in above image, specific part of my code!
I have style sheet in a project (that has been written before by another)  that it have some css codes, and inside that, like bellow, have a  property that, inside its value, it shows icon image!
i cant understand that, how inserted/created that!

my code:

```
.o-icon--close:before {
content: "";
```

}

my problem:
how he/she has written/created that icon shape inside CONTENT property.
it isn't a copy/paste an icon shape.
it isn't a text code!

as here isn't IDE, it shows a vertical rectangle, but in IDE it is shape of icon itself! like a music sign or what ever.
i know that, for CONTENT value, we can use fontawesome codes or other texts, but i can't understand how insert icon itself as a shape!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @hamed Community is a bot, you won't get a response from it. If you want to resolve any clarity issues you should [edit] your question instead of using the comments.